# elasticsearch multimatch on nested items

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

I get a string from the client. This string can match either one of the strings of my group, or one of the strings of one of the underlaying items.
This string is a must query.

i got the multimatch working for both the nested querycontainers and the normal ones. My question is: How do I get both the nested and the top layer in a single multimatch?

```
queryList.Add(q => q
            .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                .Fields(fs => fs
                    .Field(f => f.ExtraText)
                    .Field(f => f.SomeText)
                    .Field(f => f.MoreInfo)
                    .Field(f => f.SEOText)
                    .Field(f => f.Title))
                .Query(filter.SearchString)));
queryList.Add(q => q
            .Nested(c => c
                .Path(p => p.Items)
                .Query(nq => nq
                    .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                        .Fields(fs => fs
                            .Field(f => f.Items.First().Subtitle)
                            .Field(f => f.Items.First().Name)
                            .Field(f => f.Items.First().MoreInfo)
                            .Field(f => f.Items.First().ExtraText)
                            .Field(f => f.Items.First().SEOText))
                        .Query(filter.SearchString)))));
```

**Expansion:**
This search query is an expansion on an already existing number filters.
Next to the search on text there is also the filter on categories or from which country the group is:

```
if (filter.categories != null && filter.categories.Any())
        {
            foreach (string category in filter.categories)
            {
                queryList.Add(d => d
                    .Nested(nd => nd
                        .Path(np => np.Categories)
                        .Query(nq => nq
                            .Bool(nb => nb
                                .Must(fm => fm
                                    .Match(q => q
                                        .Field(f => f.Categories.First().UrlSlug)
                                        .Query(category)))))));
            }
        }
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.country))
        {
            queryList.Add(d => d.Term(p => p.country, filter.country));
        }
```

then this list of queries is fed to the search:

```
 _elasticClient.Search<ProductModel>(d => d
                        .Index(_config.GroupIndexName)
                            .Query(q => q
                                .Bool(b => b.Must(queryList))
                            )
                            .Sort(s => s
                                .Field(f => f
                                    .Field(GetSortField(filter.SortOption))
                                    .Order(filter.SortOrder)
                                )
                            )
                            .Skip((filter.Page - 1) * filter.RecordsPerPage)
                            .Take(filter.RecordsPerPage)
                        );
```

What i need is the filter for the searchstring to be 1 single query. So that on the 'must' level they don't cancel each other out.
(if the string matches the group but not one of his underlying items, neither are shown).

Answer (score 1):

[Use a `bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html). It looks like you're probably looking to combine them as `should` clauses i.e. match one *or* the other query

```
client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(sh => sh
                .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                    .Fields(fs => fs
                        .Field(f => f.ExtraText)
                        .Field(f => f.SomeText)
                        .Field(f => f.MoreInfo)
                        .Field(f => f.SEOText)
                        .Field(f => f.Title)
                    )
                    .Query(filter.SearchString)
                ), sh => sh
                .Nested(c => c
                    .Path(p => p.Items)
                    .Query(nq => nq
                        .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                            .Fields(fs => fs
                                .Field(f => f.Items.First().Subtitle)
                                .Field(f => f.Items.First().Name)
                                .Field(f => f.Items.First().MoreInfo)
                                .Field(f => f.Items.First().ExtraText)
                                .Field(f => f.Items.First().SEOText))
                            .Query(filter.SearchString)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which can be more succinctly expressed

```
client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MultiMatch(mm => mm
            .Fields(fs => fs
                .Field(f => f.ExtraText)
                .Field(f => f.SomeText)
                .Field(f => f.MoreInfo)
                .Field(f => f.SEOText)
                .Field(f => f.Title)
            )
            .Query(filter.SearchString)
        ) || q
        .Nested(c => c
            .Path(p => p.Items)
            .Query(nq => nq
                .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                    .Fields(fs => fs
                        .Field(f => f.Items.First().Subtitle)
                        .Field(f => f.Items.First().Name)
                        .Field(f => f.Items.First().MoreInfo)
                        .Field(f => f.Items.First().ExtraText)
                        .Field(f => f.Items.First().SEOText))
                    .Query(filter.SearchString)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I already use a bool query. this is just how i create the query. The problem is there are also other other filters like date that are on must level. so if it is filtered on date, the should is ignored. thats why i'm using a multimatch on must level.

Comment: It's not clear to me based on your question and this comment, what you're trying to achieve. Would you be able to elaborate in your question, perhaps adding in what the client call looks like?